# How to get all child objects of a class

Tags: c++, reflection

Is it possible to retrieve a list of child objects (of a cetain type) of an object ?

For example in this code I have an App with several available Commands. A function print all availible commands this way the user knows what he can do.
I want to iterate over each object of type Command found in App to print his doc, this way the doc updates itself automatically every time a Command is added in App.

```cpp
class Command {
public:
    std::string Name;
    std::string Description;
    virtual void Compute() = 0;
};

class StartCommand : public Command {
    std::string Name = "start";
    std::string Description = "Start the process";
    virtual void Compute() {
        // Code to start the process
    }
};

class StopCommand : public Command {
    std::string Name = "stop";
    std::string Description = "Stop the process";
    virtual void Compute() {
        // Code to stop the process
    }
};

class App {
public:
    StartCommand StartCommand;
    StopCommand StopCommand;

    void PrintAvailibleCommands() {
        std::cout << "All availible commands are: " << std::endl;
        for (Command command : this.GetObjects<Command>()) {
            std::cout << command.Name << ": " << command.Description << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

It's the `this.GetObjects<Command>()` function which does not exist and which I would like to implement.

**Do you have an idea ?**

Comment: In the constructor of Command, you could add the object to a global std::vector variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may solve your problem.

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Command {
  public:
    std::string Name;
    std::string Description;
    Command(std::string Name, std::string Description)
        : Name(Name), Description(Description) {}
    virtual void Compute() = 0;
};

class StartCommand : public Command {
  public:
    StartCommand() : Command("start", "Start the process") {}
    virtual void Compute() {
        // Code to start the process
        cout << "startcmd compute" << endl;
    }
};

class StopCommand : public Command {
  public:
    StopCommand() : Command("stop", "Stop the process") {}
    virtual void Compute() {
        // Code to stop the process
        cout << "stopcmd compute" << endl;
    }
};

class App {
  public:
    App() {
        commands.push_back(&startCommand);
        commands.push_back(&stopCommand);
    }

    StartCommand startCommand;
    StopCommand stopCommand;

    vector<Command *> commands;

    void PrintAvailableCommands() {
        std::cout << "All available commands are: " << std::endl;
        for (Command *command : commands) {
            std::cout << command->Name << ": " << command->Description
                      << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    App app;

    app.PrintAvailableCommands();
    app.startCommand.Compute();
    app.stopCommand.Compute();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what is the purpuse of the template function here, I would suggest to use a a smart pointer and the corrispondent make function instead.

Comment: Very nice !
Do you think there is a way to keep the command as a child object so you can do `app.StartCommand.Compute()`? 
With this solution it is obliged to go through the `commands` vector to access the command.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi I am not very experienced with smart pointers. How would you do it?

Comment: @CharrièreMaxime You mean `class App{public: void Compute(){ /* call every commands' Compute() */ }};  app.Compute();`?

Comment: @ABacker not to call every commands' Compute() (in which case I could do a for loop on the `commands` vector), but to call individually the one I want. With the vector, I have to call `app.commands[1].Compute()` but I don't know which command it is. I would like to be able to do `app.StartCommand.Compute()`

Comment: You could do that. But I recommend another way. `enum CommandType { START_CMD, STOP_CMD };` then `app.commands[START_CMD].Compute();`

Comment: See the update above.

Answer (score 0):

Often, I find it easier to put something into a collection directly when I want it to be there at some point.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

struct Command {
    std::string Name;
    std::string Description;
    virtual void Compute() = 0;
};

struct StartCommand : Command {
    std::string Name = "start";
    std::string Description = "Start the process";
    virtual void Compute() {
        // Code to start the process
    }
};

struct StopCommand : Command {
    std::string Name = "stop";
    std::string Description = "Stop the process";
    virtual void Compute() {
        // Code to stop the process
    }
};

struct App {
    std::tuple<StartCommand, StopCommand> commands{};

    template<class Cmd>
    static void PrintCommand(const Cmd &cmd) {
        std::cout << cmd.Name << ": " << cmd.Description << std::endl;
    }

    void PrintAvailibleCommands() {
        std::cout << "All available commands are: " << std::endl;
        std::apply([](const auto &...cmds) { (PrintCommand(cmds), ...); }, commands);
    }
};
```